# Solid Body Rotation: ω in radians/second or rotations/second?

Tags: rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity, si-units

I am just wondering if I use the solid body rotation equation

rotational energy = 1/2mr^2ω^2

and I solve for ω, and then plug in numbers, does the ω come out in radians/second, in rotations/second, or something else?

Comment: You get to choose this by your choice of units for energy, $m$, $r$, and $\omega$.  For instance, if you want $\omega$ in units of rotations per unit time, then just let $\omega \rightarrow 2 \ \pi \ \omega'$, where $\omega'$ has units of rotations per unit time.  It's just a constant offset, but again it is your choice in many ways...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If energy, mass and the radius are chosen to be in SI units it will be **radians/second**.

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian#Conversions